# How to add class with data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on some data buttons but can't figure out how to get the function working. I'm trying to add a class to an element via a data-attribute and a corresponding ID. I then want to stop the event propagation with the button inside the subject.

So far this is what I have:

**HTML:**

```
<div class ="subject" id="subject1">
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    The Subject
</div>
<div class ="subject"  id="subject2">
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    The Subject 2
</div>
<div class ="subject" id="subject3">
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    The Subject
</div>

<button class="trigger" data-subject="subject1">Trigger</button>
<button class="trigger" data-subject="subject2">Trigger</button>
<button class="trigger" data-subject="subject3">Trigger</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.active {
    color:red
}
```

**JS:**

```
var subject = document.querySelector('.subject');
var trigger = document.querySelector('.trigger');
var remove = subject.querySelector('.close');
var data = trigger.getAttribute("data-subject");

var datajs = (function () {

    function init() {

    [].forEach.call(trigger),function(btn) {
    btn.onclick = function() {this.classList.add("active");}

    });

     remove.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
     ev.stopPropagation();
     removeModalHandler();
    });
 });
     }

    init();

})();
```

and here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tNS62/1/

My JS isn't that great as you can probably see.

Comment: [*querySelector*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselector) returns a single element, the first matching the selector. [*forEach*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) requires an array–like object as its *this* (i.e. it must have a length property and numeric properties), not a DOM element. Perhaps you meant to use [*querySelectorAll*](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall).

Comment: yes, but I still don't know how to link the attribute with the ID.

Comment: `[].forEach.call(trigger),function(btn) {` is suppose to be `[].forEach.call(trigger, function(btn) {` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tNS62/3/). First we select all the buttons :

```
var triggers = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger');
var removes = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');
```

Then we apply the behavior on each button :

```
for (var i =0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
    var btn = triggers[i];
    btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var id = this.dataset.subject;
        document.querySelector('#' + id).classList.toggle('active');    
    }, false);
}
```

Use `dataset` to get the id attached to, then search the corresponding element in order to toogle the `active` class.

I made the same thing for the remove buttons.